# Cannot cure Molerat disease

Tags: fallout-4

Fallout 4 on PS4.  I cannot seem to cure Molerat disease, even though I've been to the doctor.  Is there anything like Addictol that I can craft to cure all diseases?

Comment: If you go through the whole area without getting hit, then you can [avoid the mole-rate disease completely](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/245157/79975), but that's too late now.

Comment: Someone managed to cure both himself and the boy using an obvious glitch. How haven't I thought about it before ? [How to cure yourself and Austin](https://youtu.be/4GE8BvEb1P4)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not possible to cure Molerat disease in normal game play. At the end of the quest in Vault 81, if you have contracted Molerat disease, you are offered the choice of curing yourself or curing August Engil of the disease with the only available cure. If you decide to cure him of the disease, you are granted a place to live in Vault 81, and he survives. More on the specifics of the disease can be found on the wiki [here](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Mole_rat_disease).

As to your second question, the only 'cure all' for diseases can only be found in Survival Mode, [Antibiotics](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Antibiotics). However, this will not cure Molerat disease, as the only possible way to remove it after the quest has been completed is by using console hacks or mods.

Comment: Ah, yes.  I now see other references to the Hole in the Wall quest, and the disease being permanent.  That was ages ago, and I didn't even notice that I have the disease until now, as I'm playing the Nuka World DLC.  The reason I was looking at my health status at all, is that I'm going for the All Sugared Up trophy, and was checking to see the effects of various Nuka Mix drinks.  They don't seem to be taking effect, and I thought the Molerat disease might be why.

Comment: @Alan glad to help.